# Problems with redirect, permalinks wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a wordpress site, the url was www.mysite.com/name-of-the-post

But the client change to www.mysite.com/blog/name-of-the-post

Now I have a problem with the users who click on old links, they can't access the content.

How can I solve this? I've reading about and something with regular expressions on htaccess, how can I add "/blog" when the users trying to access old links?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Where I will put this code? My htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Well i am not proficient in wordpress related issue's but please try it in your wordpress rules after ending of index.php rule only apply this much rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#internally rewriting requests to original working url
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ blog/$1 [L]`